# Problem with downloading many files from WCF

Tags: wcf, .net-3.5, streaming

I have problem with WCF service. When I am downloading 2 files everything works fine ( less than 1 minute), but when I'm trying downloading more than 3 files there is going something bad . I'm waiting and waiting and nothing :/ Every file has about 1 MB.

```
Dictionary<FileIdentifier, Stream> data = new Dictionary<FileIdentifier, Stream>();

 foreach (string path in paths)
 {

    using (var client = new ServiceClient())
    {
        var stream = client.GetFile(path);

        data[fileIdentifier] = stream;
     }

 }
```

Method at WCF Service:

```
public Stream GetFile(string path)
        {
             FileStream fs = new FileStream(stream, FileMode.Open);
            fs.Close();
            return fs;

        }
```

config of WCF service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <client />
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpBindingConfiguration" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
          openTimeout="00:15:00" receiveTimeout="00:15:00" sendTimeout="00:15:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="2097152000" maxBufferPoolSize="524288000" maxReceivedMessageSize="2097152000"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Streamed"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="524288000"
            maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="FileServer.Service" behaviorConfiguration="FileServer.Service1Behavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/Server.FileServer/Service/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address="" contract="FileServer.IService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBindingConfiguration">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
        <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. -->
        <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="FileServer.Service1Behavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" executionTimeout="1000" />
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: IIRC, that is a limitation of the HTTP spec. Not much you can do about it (as far as I know). Why are you downloading files via WCF? Surely the bandwidth overhead will be 'massive'.

Comment: I'm using this server even to downloading files which has 2gb of size, so I don't know if it is real problem with limitation of the HTTP spec :/ But I very newbie :/

Comment: @user278618: Sorry, I should mention the limitation is for concurrent connections to the same server. This is stuck at 2.

Comment: @leppie: It can be changed by setting ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit

Comment: @user278618, did the accepted answer work for you?

Comment: I tak half from Your advice, and half form Johann advice - I get stream from WCF service, and I convert it to byte[]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not close the stream on the service side.

Here is how you would do:

1. Open stream on service
2. Return stream to client
3. Read the stream on the client
4. Close the stream on the client
5. WCF will take care of closing the service stream for you

Comment: +1 Not sure why it appears to work for 1 or 2 files, but yes, you shouldn't close the stream on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning a stream, read the stream into a byte array and then return the byte array.

Comment: This would mean that the data would be buffered and the message size would be potentially huge (at 1MB per file). Streaming is the correct way to go (see @Johann's answer).